# Rails 3 - custom XML response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-3

currently i'm using this:

```
if @part.save
  format.xml  { render :xml => @part, :status => :created, :location => @part }
else
  format.xml  { render :xml => @part.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
end
```

i need a custom response, that is an xml with `<result>OK</result>` if the part was correctly saved, and `<result>OK</result>` else.

How can i do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
render :xml => {:result => "OK"}.to_xml
```

This renders

```
<result>OK</result>
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much for your answer! Please, can i ask you where could i have found this information myself?

Comment: You can find it in the rails documentation. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render